# Angular-8 : p-confirm dialog not opening on top of p-dialog of primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Angular 8 +primeng 8

We have used Primeng package
Issue : When we try to open confirm dialog of Primeng from p-dialog then its not  opening. But when we try to open confirm dialog directly from page itself then it opens correctly.

Even we tried to add appendTo="body" attribute on p-dialog and p-confirmDialog

refer below code

```
<p-confirmDialog key="deletealerts" header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"></p-confirmDialog>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `appendTo="body"` only to `p-confirmDialog` not worked though..
 is having issue for opening another

So what we did achieved for this is 
we opened another  on top of existing  and given confirmation message like view with yes/no buttons.

Comment: how you achieved that? I am facing same issue as my p-confirmDialog is hiding when I have p-dialog opened

Comment: We used two p-dialog's. one opening on another.  We avoided using p-confirmDialog as appendTo="body" not worked in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `appendTo="body"` only to `p-confirmDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `key="deletealerts"` set. If your template does not specify that key, dialog will not appear, because it will not see corresponding template.
You can either add that key to template or remove it from `p-confirmDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late but if you need a clean solution for this you can try placing your `p-confirmDialog` inside of your `p-dialog`
Something like this:

```
<p-dialog header="Test Header" [(visible)]="yourDialog" [modal]="true" [maximizable]="true" [baseZIndex]="10000"
      [draggable]="false" [resizable]="false">
      <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <p-confirmDialog header="Delete" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"></p-confirmDialog>
    
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    
      </ng-template>
</p-dialog>
```

That solved my issue.